# Which pronoun to use to denote for some people themselves?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

I just came across a sentence that I have no idea how to complete. Every pronoun that I tried (even the generic "ones") doesn't seem to fit, according to my inner grammar engine.

> Those of you who grew up in France probably saw that play in ____ childhood.

Basically, "childhood" should refer to the individual childhoods of those that grew up in France.

I'm not native, so I have no idea what I'm talking about. Without restructuring the sentence, is there a pronoun that fits?

Comment: "Your" is correct. "Your childhood" is distributive in that it applies to each member of the set "you".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct word is 'your', referring to the childhoods of the people being spoken to, although in this case it is essentially functioning as an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

You answer your own question.  Since, earlier in the sentence, you already say "Those of you", just use that for every other pronoun that represents the same group.

> Those of **you** who grew up in the 70s will always remember **your** first time seeing "Star Wars".

It's the same for other pronouns:

> Those of **us** who grew up in the 70s will always remember **our** first time seeing "Star Wars".
>
> **Those (people)** who grew up in the 70s will always remember **their** first time seeing "Star Wars".

It only becomes tricky when you want to specify a singular person, but don't want to limit it to one gender.  There are [a number of options](http://simplewriting.org/how-to-avoid-gender-biased-language-in-your-writing/) but if necessary you can use the singular "they":

> **Someone** who has read "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" will always remember **their** towel.